# Error while multiplying with python- mysql connetivity

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to multiply using python-mysql connectivity and get p but it's raising error.

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'MySQLCursor'

I don't know how to change cur statement into integer value. The code i used and the error is below.

```
def textfile():
f=open('bill.txt',"w+")
   
while True:
    conn=py.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='richajain',db='mysql')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    print("type 'STOP' to stop selecting")
    select=input("enter the name of the medicine")
    quantity=input("enter quantity")
    cur.execute('select cost from Pharmaceuticals where medname = %s',(select,))
    for i in(cur):
        print (i)
    conn.commit()
    p= cur*q
    print(p)
    no=cur.execute('select sno from Pharmaceuticals where medname = %s',(select,))
    values=(no,select,q,p)
    conn.commit() 
    y=prettytable(values)
    f.write(y)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    f.close()
    
    if select==("STOP","stop","Stop"):
        break
       
f=open('bill.txt','r')
content=f.read()
print(content)
f.close()
```

Error:

```
         Enter Your Response :  7
         type 'STOP' to stop selecting
         enter the name of the medicineOcid
         enter quantity2
         (55,)
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\medicine details.py", line 280, in <module>
         textfile()      # Function calling to update the record(s) in the table
         File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\medicine details.py", line 210, in textfile
         p= cur*q
         TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'MySQLCursor'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce easily, but i think that you should use cur.fetchone() to get element. What is output from the print(i) statement?

Comment: output of print (i) is giving this (55,)

Comment: Please insert 
```python
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
``` 
just before `p= cur*q`, and give output of myresult